# How do I print the maximum value in a column of a multidimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I find the max number in each column of  this list please I have figured how to do the row max  number but I don't understand the column part

[image: like how it is done here]

```
import random as rd
multlst = [[x for x in range(1,5+1)] for y in range(1,5+1)]
def create():
    for i in range(len(multlst)):
        for j in range(len(multlst[i])):
            multlst[i][j]= rd.randint(-100,100)

return multlst


def row():
    for i in range(0,len(multlst)):
        maxnum = max(multlst[i])
        print("The maximum value in row %s is %s"%(i,maxnum))


def col():
## how do I find the maximum value in columns of the list


 def main():

    create()
    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
  for row in multlst]))
    row()
    col()


main()
```

Comment: and what is a more pythonic way to print the multidimensional list other than  print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your multidimensional list appears to be a matrix, you might be better off using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and `numpy.max()`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
# will return a list of the maximum in each column
np.max(your_array, axis=0)
# will return a list of the maximum in each row
np.max(your_array, axis=1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to remain using the standard library, you could use a generator method inside your `max` call and ask for the value of the same index in each subsequent row. For example:

```
for col_idx in range(number_of_columns):
    maximum = max(multlst[row_idx][col_idx] for row_idx in range(number_of_rows))
    print("The maximum value in column %s is %s"%(col_idx,maximum))
```

Or simplified:

```
for col_idx in range(number_of_columns):
    maximum = max(row[col_idx] for row in multlst)
    print("The maximum value in column %s is %s"%(col_idx, maximum))
```

Comment: Thank I'm only new to python so I haven't used the numpy module but simplified answer is all I need for now